# How can I configure Hot Corners from Terminal?

Tags: command-line, slingshot

For example, how can I set **show applications menu** to the top-left corner?

Comment: Are you asking how to configure it **from** the command line?

Comment: yes, the answer is just what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done via gsettings.

1. Find the key you need(play around with grep to find the exact key, its easy):

   ```
   # gsettings list-recursively | grep hotcorner
   org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-custom-command ''
   org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-bottomright 'none'
   org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-topright 'none'
   org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-bottomleft 'window-overview'
   org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-topleft 'none'
   ```
2. Next - set it (example below sets top-left corner to open slingshot, the applications menu):

   ```
   # gsettings set  org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-topleft 'open-launcher'
   ```